# I want to make the wax material used in the intro to daredevil

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, materials, node-editor

so im looking to make a melting wax material, I figured out the wax part. but not the waves and the dark wax drips in it. 
i would love to find out how to animate it as well. I tried the wave node but it was not satisfactory. 
This has the texture i'm looking for in it https://youtu.be/KFYFh8w4758?t=11
Thank you :)

Comment: there's a guy who has tried it in Blender, he explains briefly how he did it in the comments section: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tx9ch7izVac    also a discussion on this topic here: https://blenderartists.org/t/daredevil-intro/664835/2